# A way to simplify getting a remainder

Tags: c++, modulo

Excuse the title, I couldn't find a better way to express the issue. Anyways, I don't have any sort of error, but I want to know if there is a way to simplify this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{

    const int Lbs_per_stone = 14;

    int lbs;

    std::cout << "Enter your weight in pounds: ";
    std::cin >> lbs;
    int stone = lbs / Lbs_per_stone; // whole stone
    int pounds = lbs % Lbs_per_stone; // remainder in pounds

    std::cout << lbs << " pounds are " << stone << " stone, " << pounds << " 
    pound(s)." << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

to where I don't have to declare two separate integers to output both the number in stone and remainder in pounds. Is there any possible way to do this a better way?

Comment: Simplify it how?  You don't need to store the result in variables if you don't want to.

Comment: `I don't have to input two separate integers` You are only inputting one integer, what do you mean?

Comment: By simplify, I mean is there a more efficient method to doing this? I want to make this as efficient as possible.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice I said that. Sheesh, I'm tired. What I mean't to say was instead of using two separate variables. I feel like this could be done with one Int type variable. ( Ill edit that I said that).

Comment: efficiency for code this trivial isnt going to make much of a difference as far as runtime is concerned

Comment: @Jake2k13 : This code is about as simple as it gets.  On some architectures, it'll even combine your `/` and `%` into a single "divmod" operation.  Don't overthink it unless it's an actual bottleneck.  And if you ever do think you have a performance issue, profile and measure first.  If you want to get a good feel for what kind of code the compiler generates from your input, you can always ask GCC / G++ to output the assembly version... but you're in for a long journey if you truly want to understand what it's doing and what actually matters.

Comment: For divisions and remainders your compiler is likely to generate more efficient code than you will.  I'd stick with clearly expressing what you want and letting the compiler handle any clever bit shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you could do if this bothers you:

**Use a class**

```
template <typename T>
struct Div_Mod
{
    Div_Mod(T a, T b) : div(a/b), mod(a % b) { }
    T div, mod;
};

Div_Mod<int> weight(lbs, LBS_PER_STONE);
std::cout << weight.div << ' ' << weight.mod << '\n';
```

**Ensuring optimal machine code**

If you're bothered that you're doing a machine code operation to get each of the `/` and `%` results, then you probably shouldn't be - your optimiser should take care of that, but if you insist on being certain you can use try `std::div` et al as suggested by Pete Becker which may use that optimisation, but if it doesn't then look for a compiler- or OS-provided instrinsic or use a CPU-specific inline assembly for an instruction like http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html

Answer (score 2):

Read about `std::div`, declared in `<cstdlib>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store them in variables, then don't:

```
int main()
{
    const int LBS_PER_STONE = 14;
    int lbs;
    std::cout << "Enter weight in pounds:  ";
    std::cin >> lbs;
    std::cout << "Your weight is " << (lbs / LBS_PER_STONE) << " and " << (lbs % LBS_PER_STONE) << " pounds" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know it was a "newbie" question. I am self taught, and just curious for future development. Would this be the most efficient setup for this particular program you think?

Comment: For a program this small, clear, and easy for the compiler to optimize it isn't going to matter if you store intermediate results in variables or not.

Comment: @Jake2k13 The issue appears to be that you are focused on premature optimization.  In order to properly optimize something, you must profile it to identify the bottlenecks and improve upon them.  With code this small, there isn't much you can optimize.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mean something obvious like:

```
std::cout << lbs << " pounds are " << (lbs / lbs_per_stone)
     << " stone and " << (lbs % lbs_per_stone) << pound(s)." << std::endl;
```

The only other way to save an int (without using temporaries) is by deducting the stones from lbs:

```
std::cout << lbs << " pounds are ";

int stone = lbs / lbs_per_stone;
lbs -= stone * lbs_per_stone;

std::cout << stone << " stone and " << lbs << pound(s)." << std::endl;
```

Hope this helps